# Query posts in a category and include only one post per author?

Tags: query-posts, author

I'm attempting to list posts from a category (a random selection). However, I only want to display one post per author. Thoughts? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can this help you? -- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/query-post-to-show-one-post-per-author

ps. I should add this as a comment, but I can't, sorry.